# Use undefined variables in Selenium IDE for if condition

Tags: javascript, integration-testing, selenium-ide

I want to run a "child" test at the end of a "parent" test that clears the session cookie if the flag `skipReset` has not been set. Further, I'd like to run a "grandparent" test that calls the "parent" test and sets `skipReset = true` which should make the "child" test skip the reset and thus keep the session data (see print screen).

However if the "child" test was run from a parent which did not set the flag `skipReset` the test fails.

[image: Failed Selenium child test]

I'd like to do this so the "parent" test does not have to be copy pasted into the "grand parent" test excluding the session reset line. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a workaround which works for the intended use.

I set a JavaScript sessionStorage variable in the "grandparent" test and check in the "child" test if that JavaScript sessionStorage variable is not undefined and correct.

Make sure to open a page before setting the sessionStorage variable so it is persistent through out each page change. See print screens of the grandparent and child tests.

[image: Grandparent test]

The parent test only consists of the following code:

```
open | /other-page
run  | Reset session // Child test
```

[image: Child test]

This way the "child" test only executes the reset code if no test in the chain has defined the JavaScript variable `skipReset`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "${skipReset}" == "$" + "{skipReset}"
```

Just use string comparision, unset variable in IDE means that there weren't any substitution, so it just remains litterally as it was written ('${skipReset}').

Answer (score 0):

I set such variables in '1' to know should 'child' function run or not. If variable is undifined or '0', 'child' function will not run.

```
store | 1 | flag    or    store | 0 | flag

if | ${flag} == 1|
code here...
end| |
```

Comment: You now have the same problem, if flag is undefined the test fails.